# Google sheets - Combine rows from one column, until a specific character is detected

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Lets say i have column A

```
          A
```

"|---|----|--|-|----|-------|--

--|----|--|"

|-----| | | | |------

----------|--------------

-----|----| |"

And i want to make it like this:

```
             B
```

|---|----|--|-|----|-------|----|----|--|"

|-----| | | | |-----------------------------------|----| | |"

So if B is the correct form(where " marks the end of the wanted row and the beginning of the next) but i have the information separated into smaller rows like column A, how can i convert column A to look like B, can it be made with formula which converts all information into one row until it sees " and then goes on a new row and repeats the process until it reaches the bottom for the column? I tried functions like JOIN, CONCAT, TEXTJOIN but i can't make it work. I also checked for options in Notepad but couldn't find a solution. Also tried with Excel. I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: You'll need to share an actual sheet probably to properly get your question across.

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string manipulation, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  transpose( 
    split( 
      join("", A2:A), 
      """", false, true 
    ) 
  ) 
  & """"  
)
```